# java get user's home directory of the non current user on *NIX

Tags: java, linux, unix

I came across `System.getProperty("user.home")` in java, but I want a way in which I can get the home directory of another user that's not the current user for a UNIX like system.

Answer (score 3):

Java has no such knowledge of the host system. However the information is present in the [`/etc/passwd`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/) file. One approach is to manually parse this file, given you have sufficient permissions.

Comment: This will work only if current user has permissions to read this file.

Comment: This will not work for users which are not defined locally, but instead defined in, for example, an LDAP directory.